# Relative positioning inside absolute?

Tags: css

Here's what I have:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="absolute">
  <img src="/test.jpg">
  <div>This is an image</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The container is relative and absolute div is absolute, with a bottom of 0 so it sits at the bottom of my container.

Inside the absolute div I would like to centre an image and text so they sit side by side (not underneath each other).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `div` to `display: inline` (or use an element that isn't a block by default), and make sure the container is wide enough to hold them.

(This, however, is *normal flow*, not relative positioning. Relative positioning offsets an element from its natural position (leaving a gap))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#absolute{position:absolute;bottom:0;text-align:center;width:100%;}
#absolute *{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fKKm/)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option would be to change the inside div (with the text to be beside the image) to a span in lieu of a div, or add the style display:inline to that div

Ala:

Option 2:

```
<img src="/test.jpg">
<div style="display:inline;">This is an image</div>
```